# Prove that KKT matrix has at least $n-m$ positive and $m$ negative eigenvalues.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nonlinear-optimization, block-matrices

I would like to prove that KTT matrix defined below has at least $n-m$ positive and at least $m$ negative eigenvalues.

$$ K:= \begin{bmatrix} H & A^{T} \\ A & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

where $H \in \Bbb R^{n \times n}$ is symmetric, $A \in \Bbb R^{m \times n}$ full rank, $\operatorname{rank} (A) = m$. Assume $H$ is positive definite , $x^{T} H x > 0$ on the nullspace of $A$, $A x = 0$ where $x \neq 0$.

I also wonder if we can say that null($H$) spans the same vectors as null($A$) since it is on the null($A$)? What is the intuitive meaning of being on the nullspace of a matrix? Any hints would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This question is equivalent to exercise $10.1$ of the book [Convex Optimization](http://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/) by Stephen Boyd and Lieven Vandenberghe.

The answer can be found in [this](https://see.stanford.edu/materials/lsocoee364a/hw8sol.pdf) pdf, which contains the solutions of homework 8 from Prof. Boyd's EE364a-Convex Optimization I course.

Edit: The answer to question 10.1 of the book is transcribed bellow, in case the course website is taken down.

**10.1 - Solution**

(a)

- *Conditions 1 and 2*. If $x \in \mathcal{N}(A) ∩ \mathcal{N}(P)$, $x \neq 0$, then $Ax = 0, x \neq 0$, but $x^TP x = 0$, contradicting the second statement. Conversely, suppose the second statement fails to hold, *i.e.*, there is an $x$ with $Ax = 0$, $x \neq 0$, but $x^TP x = 0$. Since $P \geq 0$, we conclude $P x = 0$, *i.e.*, $x ∈ \mathcal{N}(P)$, which contradicts the first statement.
- *Conditions 2 and 3.* If $Ax = 0$, $x \neq 0$, then $x$ must have the form $x = F z$, where $z \neq 0$ because $\mathbf{rank}(F) = n−p$. Then we have $x^TP x = z^TF^TP F z > 0$.
- *Conditons 2 and 4*. If the second condition holds then
  $$
  x^T(P + A^TA)x = x^TP x + \| A^T x \|^2_2 > 0$$
  for all nonzero $x$, so the last statement holds with $Q = I$. If the last statement holds for some $Q \geq 0$ then $$
  x^T(P + A^TQA)x = x^TP x + x^TA^TQAx > 0$$
  for all nonzero $x$. Therefore if $Ax = 0$ and $x \neq 0$, we must have $x^TP x > 0$.

Now let us show that the four statements are equivalent to nonsingularity of the KKT matrix. First suppose that $x$ satisfies $Ax = 0$, $P x = 0$, and $x \neq 0$. Then
$$\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
P & A^T \\
A & 0
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
x \\
0
\end{array}
\right]=0,$$
which shows that the KKT matrix is singular.

Now suppose the KKT matrix is singular, *i.e.*, there are $x$, $z$, not both zero, such that
$$\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
P & A^T \\
A & 0
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
x \\
z
\end{array}
\right]=0.$$
This means that $P x + A^Tz = 0$ and $Ax = 0$, so multiplying the first equation on the left by $x^T$, we find $x^TP x + x^TA^Tz = 0$. Using $Ax = 0$, this reduces to $x^TP x = 0$, so we have $P x = 0$ (using $P \geq 0$). This contradicts (a), unless $x = 0$. In this case, we must have $z \neq 0$. But then $A^Tz = 0$ contradicts $\mathbf{rank} (A) = p$.

(b)

From part (a), $P + A^TA > 0$. Therefore there exists a nonsingular matrix $R \in \mathbf{R}^{n \times n}$ such that$$
R^T(P + A^TA)R = I.$$
Let $AR = UΣV^T_1$ be the singular value decomposition of $AR$, with $U \in \mathbf{R}^{p \times p}$, $\Sigma = \mathbf{diag}(σ_1, . . . , σ_p) \in \mathbf{R}^{p \times p}$ and $V_1 \in \mathbf{R}^{n \times p}$. Let $V_2 \in \mathbf{R}^{n \times (n-p)}$ be such that $$
V = [V_1 V_2]$$
is orthogonal, and define $$
S =[Σ \ 0 ] \in \mathbf{R}^{p \times n}.$$

We have $AR = USV^T$, so $$
V^TR^T(P + A^TA)RV = V^TR^TP RV + S^T S = I.$$
Therefore $V^TR^TP RV = I − S^T S$ is diagonal. We denote this matrix by Λ: $$
Λ = V^TR^TP RV = \mathbf{diag}(1 − σ^2_1, \dots, 1 − σ^2_p, 1, \dots , 1).$$

Applying a congruence transformation to the KKT matrix gives
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
V^TR^T & 0 \\
0 & U^T
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
P & A^T \\
A & 0
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
RV & 0 \\
0 & U
\end{array}
\right] = 
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\Lambda & S^T \\
S & 0
\end{array}
\right]
,$$
and the inertia of the KKT matrix is equal to the inertia of the matrix on the right.

Applying a permutation to the matrix on the right gives a block diagonal matrix with $n$ diagonal blocks
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\lambda_i & \sigma_i \\
\sigma_i & 0
\end{array}
\right]
, \quad i = 1, \dots , p, \quad λ_i = 1, \quad i = p + 1, \dots , n.
$$
The eigenvalues of the $2 \times 2$-blocks are
$$
\frac{\lambda_i \pm \sqrt{\lambda^2_i + 4 \sigma^2_i }}{2} 
$$

*i.e.*, one eigenvalue is positive and one is negative. We conclude that there are $p + (n − p) = n$ positive eigenvalues and $p$ negative eigenvalues.

Comment: Course websites are often taken offline at one point or another. It would be best to copy the solution into your answer (with a citation).

Comment: Thanks for the help! I have recently acquired the book you have mentioned .

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short proof based on Cauchy Eigenvalue Interlacing.

**positive eigenvalues**
by rank nullity note that $\dim \ker A \geq n-m$
let $\big\{\mathbf x_1, \dots, \mathbf x_{n-m}\big\}$ be basis for a subspace of $\ker A$, and chosen to be orthonormal with respect to the dot product.

We have $V^T V= I_{n-m}$ with
$V:= \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf x_1 & \mathbf x_2 & \cdots & \mathbf x_{n-m} \\ \mathbf 0& \mathbf 0& \cdots & \mathbf 0 \end{bmatrix}$   and

$V^T K V= V^T \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf 0 & A^{T} \\ A & \mathbf 0 \end{bmatrix} V + V^T  \begin{bmatrix} H & \mathbf 0 \\ \mathbf 0 & \mathbf 0 \end{bmatrix}V = V^T  \begin{bmatrix} H & \mathbf 0 \\ \mathbf 0 & \mathbf 0 \end{bmatrix}V \succ \mathbf 0$  since $H$ is PD in this subspace.  By Cauchy Interlacing $K$ has at least $n-m$ eigenvalues $\gt 0$.

[Side note: if we chose to first prove that $K$ is invertible (a simple blocked argument) then we could slightly modify this to show that $K$ has $n$ eigenvalues $\geq 0$ by Interlacing and the inequality is strict since $K$ is invertible.]

**negative eigenvalues**
$\text{rank}\big(A\big)=m$ so $A$ has some set of $m$ linearly independent columns.  Now the other $d$ columns of $A$ i.e. columns with indices $\big\{j_1, j_2, \cdots, j_d\big\}$ are in the span of those $m$ column of $A$.  So delete columns $\big\{j_1, j_2, \cdots, j_d\big\}$ of $K$. To retain symmetry delete the same set of indices of rows of $K$ i.e. delete rows $\{j_1, j_2, \cdots, j_d\big\}$ as well.  We now have

$K':= \begin{bmatrix} H' & (A')^{T} \\ A' & \mathbf 0_{m \times m} \end{bmatrix}$ where $K'$ is a $2m \times 2m$ principal submatrix of $K$ so the eigenvalues of $K'$ interlace with those of $K$.  This means the desired claim  follows if we can show $K'$ has $m$ negative eigenvalues.

We know $K'$ is invertible because $K'P =  \begin{bmatrix} (A')^T & H' \\ \mathbf 0_{m \times m} & A'  \end{bmatrix}$ for some permutation matrix $P$ and
$0 \lt \det\big(A'\big)^2 =\det\big((A')^T\big)\det\big(A'\big)= \det\big(K'P\big) = \Big\vert\det\big(K'P\big)\Big \vert = \Big\vert\det\big(K'\big)\Big \vert $

Now $K'$ represents a $2m \times 2m$ non-degenerate real symmetric bilinear (or complex hermitian) form with an $m$ dimensional totally isotropic subspace, given by its bottom right corner.  Then $K'$ has signature $(m,m)$ -- i.e. $m$ eigenvalues $\lt 0$ which completes the proof.  Ref  [An exercise of non-degenerate Hermitian form.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3730546/an-exercise-of-non-degenerate-hermitian-form/) -- I suggest the Interlacing proof as it is shortest and similar in spirit to this proof.